# Azure Redis Cache Private Endpoint Test?

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache, azure-private-link

I have created a private endpoint for Azure Redis Cache, everything is created with no errors and seems to check out but I am not sure how to confirm the traffic flow. Normally with a private endpoint, if I have a VM in the same Vnet that hosts the subnet for the private endpoint resource, I can use a 'nslookup' command to check the endpoint and I would see that the private IP is returned instead of the public IP. In the Redis Cache case, I am still getting the public IP. My nslookup command is standard like this: nslookup myrediscacheresource.redis.cache.windows.net.

Any guidance on how to test this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to my problem. It turns out my VNET is joined to a custom DNS Server. To solve this issue, I need to go to those DNS servers, add "conditional forwarder" to go to Azure public DNS 168.63.129.16.

For others who maybe interested in understanding more details, this blog post provided great details on how Azure Private Link and DNS works: https://bloggerz.cloud/2020/12/18/azure-private-link-and-dns/